# Regex to match `xyz` in `abc|qw|xzy mno`

Tags: c#, regex

It's driving nuts.

The input strings are:

```
abc|qw|xzy mno
abc||xzy mno
abc|qw|xzy
abc|qw|
```

I need to extract the first word (if any) after the 2nd vertical bar, in all cases above `xyz` but in general words in multiple (natural) languages.

Also, all lines must be considered as a block so `single line` does not apply, iow, the EOL is the break to account for.

Thank you, guys.

Comment: Does it have to be regex?  I could C# this together in seconds with its string match stuff.

Comment: What code did you try? The "all lines must be considered as a block" part is rather unclear.

Comment: Split by newline, loop over elements, split by `|`, take the third element, split by space, take the first element. Don't know C#, but this shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: how about ```"abc|qw|xzy mno".Split(' ')[0].Split('|')[2]``` ?

Comment: `var res = s.Split('|')?.Skip(2)?.Take(1)?.FirstOrDefault()?.Split(' ')?.FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Thanks but split won't do. The input is fed to a library that requires a regex.

Comment: And what are the restrictions then? Can you access groups? What have you tried?

Comment: Barmar below got it. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regexp with the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option.

```
(?<=^(?:[^|]*\|){2})\w+
```

`(?<=` begins a positive lookbehind, so this matches a word that must be preceded by the beginning of the line followed by two pipe-delimited sequences.

Comment: This one did it `(?<=^(?:[^|]*\|){2})\S+`